# IBM MobileFirst Worklight 8.0 : How to disable direct update?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to disable updates in my android application.

Is it possible to disable direct updates worklight 8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct update is triggered only for Cordova applications. Direct update triggers when you make changes to the webresources and upload the updated webresources archive to the server.
This is done via the CLI command:

`mfpdev app webupdate`

Once the updated web package has been uploaded into the server, next time the Cordova application connects to the server, MobileFirst server triggers direct update.

If you do not want direct update, you should not upload the updated webresources archive to the server.

More details on this topic can be found [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/direct-update/).